# Haskell: Frequent values

Tags: haskell, segment-tree

I am trying to solve [frequent values](https://www.bnuoj.com/v3/problem_show.php?pid=14333) using Segment Tree

[This](http://andrew-algorithm.blogspot.com/2014/09/uva-problem-11235-frequent-values.html) blog article uses a similar approach

I want to split a list into intervals as:

`-1 -1 1 1 1 1 3 10 10 10` becomes `(0, 2) (2, 6) (6, 7), (7, 10)`

I have a code as:

```
g s = map (\x->(head x, length x)) . group . sort $ s
```

But it does not give the correct output.

Is it possible with frequent values too?

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it as

```
f = neighbors . prefixSums . counts
  where
    counts = map length . group . sort
    prefixSums = scanl (+) 0
    neighbors xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

This starts by computing the `counts` of elements, so your (arbitrary permutation of) `[-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 10, 10, 10]` becomes `[2, 4, 1, 3]`.

Then, `prefixSums` computes the sums of prefixes, and so we get `[0, 2, 6, 7, 10]` for our running example.

To get the end result, we simply take the consecutive `neighbors` of this list.

Comment: Can you help me with understanding the blog article?